# NHibernate and missing constructor code

Tags: nhibernate, constructor

When loading through NH the default constructor is used and then every property in the map is set. That is fine by me.

But what if I have some logic in the constructor? Could I register a method to be called after the NH construction?

e.g. (it could me more complicated and involves several properties)

```
public class Person
{
    string name;
    int? age;
    DateTime ageStamp;

    public Person(string name, int? age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        if (age!=null)
        {
            this.age = age;
            ageStamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a pseudo code for what you want to do.

Comment: added an example, but it could me more complicated and involves several properties

Answer (score 1):

You can create a private default constructor.

NHibernate needs a default constructor in order to be able to construct the object when loading an entity from the database.
Once constructed, NHibernate will set all the properties or members with the data that exists in the DB.

My opinion, is that NHibernate should just restore the entity with data coming from the DB, and that it should execute no other logic, that could affect the state of the object.

Comment: But when the parameters ctor will be called? call it after the default one is doing things twice, allocate memory twice, and just weird

Comment: but i need a event after the data has been loaded.

Comment: Some logic is important to be executed in the contructor ... or else you are saying that constructors are obsolete. Just because NH is newing my domain, constructor code are still important for many things.

Comment: A constructor can only be called once per object.  NH needs the default constructor; otherwise it doesn't know how to create the instance. It will not call the constructor with parameters. Therefore, you'll need the default-constructor.  You can mark it private so that *you* cannot call it, and are forced to use the constructor with parameters.  When you need additional logic to be executed after NH has loaded an entity, you can use Interceptors or Nhibernate events.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an interceptor and override Instantiate().

e.g.:

```
public interface IInitializable
{
    void Initialize();
}

public class InitializingInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override object Instantiate(string clazz, EntityMode entityMode, object id)
    {
        object result = base.Instantiate(clazz, entityMode, id);

        var initializable = result as IInitializable;
        if(initializable!=null)
            initializable.Initialize();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how will you supply name and age to the Initialize method?

Comment: @Jamie NHibernate has already hydrated those properties in the base Instantiate method

Comment: .. this doesn't work the Instantiate event is before the properties has been set. :(